# Run scrapy crawl with cron and save to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, cron, scrapy

I'm running a scrapy spider to scrape websites using cron job and mongodb. When I run a regular scrapy crawl, it works and save to mongodb. However, when I run it using cron, it doesn't save to the database.  Log output shows regular crawl results, only that it doesn't save to mongodb. What am I missing here? My guess is that it's something regarding scrapy's environment because I can use mongo save() inside individual spiders and get the desired result but not when I put it inside the pipeline.

Thanks!

```
**crontab -e** 
PATH=/home/ubuntu/crawlers/env/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
*/15 * * * * /home/ubuntu/crawlers/env/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/crawlers/spider/evilscrapy/evilscrapy/run.py > /tmp/output

**pipeline**
class EvilscrapyPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        connection = MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT']
        )
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

    def process_item(self,item,spider):      
        self.log_record(item)
        print(item)
        if item['url']:
                if self.collection.find( { "url": item['url'] } ).count() == 0:
                    if item['title']:
                        if item['content']:
                            item['timestamp']=datetime.datetime.now()
                            self.collection.insert(item)
        return item
```

Differences in output from running '/home/ubuntu/crawlers/env/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/crawlers/spider/evilscrapy/evilscrapy/run.py > /tmp/output' on my terminal vs cron job shows that processes do not run past mongo db commands.

specifically, inside the link_spider, the log stops after the mongodb call:

```
lib_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '../../../', 'server'))
if lib_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path[0:0] = [lib_path]
from mongo import save_mongo, check_mongo

class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def parse(self, response):
        ''' code to get urls to complete_list '''
        for url in complete_list:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
            print "log"

        if check_mongo(url):
            print "log2"
```

log seems to stops here.

My mongo_connector file:

```
import json
import os
import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient
from scrapy.conf import settings


def check_mongo(url):
    connection = MongoClient()
    db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
    collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]
    if collection.find( { "url": url } ).count() != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

and settings:

```
MONGODB_SERVER = "localhost"
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
MONGODB_DB = 'articles'
MONGODB_COLLECTION = 'articles_data'
```

mongod.log:

```
2017-05-01T21:12:40.926+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2017-05-01T21:12:40.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4249 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ubuntu
2017-05-01T21:12:40.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.12
2017-05-01T21:12:40.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ef3e1bc78e997f0d9f22f45aeb1d8e3b6ac14a14
2017-05-01T21:12:40.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-05-01T21:12:40.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-05-01T21:12:40.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-05-01T21:12:40.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-05-01T21:12:40.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-05-01T21:12:40.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-05-01T21:12:40.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-05-01T21:12:40.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo$
2017-05-01T21:12:40.961+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage en$
2017-05-01T21:12:40.961+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=4G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics$
2017-05-01T21:12:41.300+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2017-05-01T21:12:41.300+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2017-05-01T21:12:41.301+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-05-02T19:52:06.590+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T19:52:06.590+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T20:08:58.458+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T20:08:58.458+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T20:08:58.458+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T20:21:39.076+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T20:21:39.076+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T20:21:39.076+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T20:21:39.076+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T21:33:09.651+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T21:33:09.651+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T21:33:09.651+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T21:33:09.651+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T22:01:53.036+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T22:01:53.036+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T22:01:53.036+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
2017-05-02T22:01:53.036+0000 I COMMAND  [conn46674] killcursors: found 0 of 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, processes started by crontab have their own minimum environment. That often causes problems when starting complex processes that rely on particular environment variables.

To fix this try adding . $HOME/.profile in front of your command in crontab. For example:

```
PATH=/home/ubuntu/crawlers/env/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
*/15 * * * * $HOME/.profile; /home/ubuntu/crawlers/env/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/crawlers/spider/evilscrapy/evilscrapy/run.py > /tmp/output
```

Comment: I'm trying your solution out... Not seeing any progress yet.

Comment: Sorry to hear this. Can you post your scrapy's and mongodb's logs here?

Comment: No worries, thanks for helping out.  It seems to me that the problem is mongodb connection during the cron job... updated the question with relevant files needed. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Thanks, checked your updated question and to me it looks suspicious that the scrapy log just stops at the mongodb call. My first guess is there is an exception or error message with helpful information that doesn't have a chance to bubble up. Try upping the log levels and look for exception-catchalls that might eat away the error message.

Comment: Ah you are right I added other log levels and now get 'TypeError: name must be an instance of str' for mongo db connection.  Looking into it now. Thanks

Comment: I noticed that mongodb is not working due to it not reading from the settings file.  And scrapy pipelines is not included as well.  Just hardcoded the db settings variables and moved pipeline to another file for now